# Upload a .csv file into PHP MySQL database without column headings

Tags: php, excel

I want to upload .csv files into MySQL database using PHP. I have this code:

```
<?php
   include_once 'db.php';
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   if($_FILES['csv_data']['name']){
   $arrFileName = explode('.',$_FILES['csv_data']['name']);
   if($arrFileName[1] == 'csv'){
   $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_data']['tmp_name'], "r");
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection,$data[0]);
   $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection,$data[1]);
   $import="INSERT into tbl_csv values('','$item1','$item2')";
   mysqli_query($dbConnection,$import);
  }
   fclose($handle);
   print "Import done";
  }
 }
  else{

  echo "only Excel";
 }
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>CSV Upload</title>
<head>
<body>
 <form method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
 Upload CSV: <input type='file' name='csv_data' /> <input type='submit'      name='submit' value='import' />
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

It is working properly. But I want to upload .csv files without their column headings. For example if I upload files like:

```
id item1  item2
1   a      b
2   b      c
```

each time the `id`, `item1` and `item2` will be inserted.

How to solve this?

Comment: where is your download code??

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple just put the following above to the while loop:

```
$headers = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection,$data[0]);
  $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbConnection,$data[1]);
....
```